# Serving Static Files in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles, heroku-cli

I have a Django and React app hosted on Heroku, the issue is that it does not see my files but everything is completely working in my localhost. It was built successfully on Heroku.

Debugging process:

**Project built successfully**

[image: Deployed Project]

**Opens App**

Returns a blank page meaning it is not serving my CSS and js files.

[image: Blank app]

**Checked Developer tools**

The Django app requires the CSS and js files to show the template

[image: developer tools]

**Checked Heroku logs**

Heroku returns err 404 for those files

[image: Heroku Logs]

**Check my Deployed files in Heroku**

I checked to see my files that are deployed in Heroku in my terminal, and they are there.

[image: Heroku deployed files]

**Setting**

```py
import django_heroku
import os
from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'storages',
    'cloudinary_storage',
    'cloudinary',

    'base.apps.BaseConfig',
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}


SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=30),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/click2buy/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    BASE_DIR / 'frontend/build/static'
]


MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/images'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage'

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

if os.getcwd() == '/app':
    DEBUG = False

CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
    'CLOUD_NAME': config('CLOUD_NAME'),
    'API_KEY': config('API_KEY'),
    'API_SECRET': config('API_SECRET'),
}

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Now, I'm confused, why is it not serving the files, it's not a code problem cos everything is working well in my localhost. Any solutions pls?
Thanks.

Comment: please share the settings.py in code not image

Comment: @sarangkkl done, but I don't think there is a problem with the code cos it's working on my localhost without errors

Comment: let me know is your issue is solved

Comment: @sarangkkl I've fixed it, all i just did was run `python manage.py collectstatic` then redeploy to heroku and it worked

Answer (score 0):

One Thing you need to understand that Heroku does not provide support to serve your static files you need to use tools like s3 bucket to server static files one more issue i find that your database i have used aws rds free version postgres database by which you can solve your query [here is the video which might help you what you are lacking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFFtDLZnbSs&t=443s)

good Luck